# Help understanding a statement from a proof that is supposedly 'easy to check'.

Tags: functions, set-theory

I am reading a book on the Banach Tarski Paradox by Stan Wagon, and I came across a part of the proof of the Banach Schroder Bernstein Theorem that I can't understand.

> Let $f:A \to B_{1}$ and $g:A_{1} \to B$ where $A_{1} \subseteq A$ and $B_{1} \subseteq B$. (We know these bijections exist by an earlier part of the proof.)
>   Let $C_{0}=A$\ $A_{1}$and for $n \geq 1$, $C_{n+1}=g^{-1}f(C_{n})$.
>   Let $C=\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}C_{n}$. Then it is easy to check that $g(A$\ $C)$=$B$\ $f(C)$

It says it is easy to check, but I can't see why it is true! I guess it's something simple that I am missing, and would appreciate it if someone could explain the statement. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can proceed by double inclusion :

First suppose $x\in A\setminus C$. $g(x) \in B$ is obvious given the definitions, but now assume $g(x) = f(c)$ for some $c\in C$.

Then $c\in C_n$ for some $n$, so that $g^{-1}f(c) = x\in C_{n+1} \subset C$, which is absurd.

Conversely, let $b\in B\setminus f(C)$. Well $b= g(a)$ for some $a\in A_1$, so what we need to do is check that $a\notin C$. But if $a\in C$, then $a\in C_0$ or $a\in C_{n+1}$ for some $n$.

If $a\in C_0$, then $a\notin A_1$, which is absurd.

Thus $a\in g^{-1}f(C_n)$ for some $n$, so that $b=g(a) \in f(C_n) \subset f(C)$, which is again absurd.

Thus $a\in A\setminus C$, so $b\in g(A\setminus C)$ : we are done.

Comment: Thank you for your help!